# Can someone provide a real, correct and genuine sources.list for Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 15.04, software-sources

I have been using Ubuntu for a while now and I have been having all problems that I needed not to post a thread for to get answers, until I recently upgraded to Ubuntu Vivid.

Ubuntu is great but each time I run `sudo apt-get update` I have a smooth run of update which return a notice of a duplicate in `/var/lib/apt/lists`.

That is not even where the problem lies. What is very frustrating is that even when I run the proposed update, it still produces the same result.

I was using Ubuntu 14.04 then I upgraded to Ubuntu Utopic before upgrading to Vivid.

All I need is someone to please provide a compact without duplicates source list.

Please.

Thank you all in advance.

Edit: This is the new error I got from reloading the software-properties-gtk.

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/universe i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid-security_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories

Comment: If you post the content of your sources.list, maybe we can help you to spot the duplicates. It is not the whole line that needs to be exact, because each line can contain multiple repos.

Comment: it will not allow me to post picture or the error message because it appears to be links to the repos more than 2, cos I'm a noob

Comment: @MarcoOz You can post the full error message by pasting it in, selecting it, and pressing Ctrl+K (or clicking the `{}` tool in the editing toolbar). This formats it as code, which will make it display more correctly, and has the additional benefit that code-formatted URLs are not automatically linkified--thus it won't make your post have more than two links in it. As for a screenshot, I highly recommend posting the *text* of the error message but if you wish to post an image you can upload it somewhere like http://postimage.org or http://imgur.com, give the link, and someone can add it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my virgin `sources.list`

Duplicates can also arise when entries are included in `sources.list` and in the files in the folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-GNOME 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Alpha amd64 (20150316)]/ vivid main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid partner
```

You can remove duplicates with *Y PPA Manager*:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

Run *Y PPA Manager*

[image]

Select *Advanced*

[image]

Select *Scan and remove duplicate PPAs*

When this is complete, then start an update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I want to thank everybody that took the time to look at this problem I am having. I want to say that I have taken the time to follow step by step of the provided guidances but still my sudo apt-get update brings the Dupes notice. Could it be just me or this a serious bug in the new release?

Comment: @MarcoOz Do not thank me, give me an upvote :)

Comment: @MarcoOz Maybe you have duplicate along with the files in this folder: "/etc/apt/sources.list.d"

Comment: A.B. I looked through that folder but there is nothing like that. All the files there are all of the same order. For instance, google-chrome.list, google-chrome.list.distupgrade, google-chrome.list.save and all in that order for all files. Noe repetitions.

Comment: @MarcoOz Another idea. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @MarcoOz Improved :)

Comment: Improved? Where is the improved answer ;)

Comment: @MarcoOz The part with the "Y PPA Manager"

Comment: I have just finished doing that and it found 3 duplicates which I removed. Sadly, I got the same duplicate bug when I run sudo pat-get update but this time some notices about NO_PUBKEY for several others. How come?

Comment: @MarcoOz In Y-PPA-Manager is an option "Advanced > Try to import all missing GPG keys".

Comment: @MarcoOz Move your entire files from /etc/apt/sources.list.d in a backup directory. Then `apt-get update`. Then copy every single file with the extension "list" back. And run every time "apt-get update". Then the error should occur sometime back and you know in which file is the problem.

Comment: This is the new error I got from reloading the software-properties-gtk

Comment: @MarcoOz Where is the error?

Comment: Trying to post it here but I was told I can't post more than 2 links cos I need at least 10 reputation. So I wonder how I'm gonna be able to make anyone know what the heck of a problem I am facing using my ubuntu vivid. And posting the error text here won't allow due to limited character spaces.......Really?

Comment: Update your Question. Add the error message. That should be possible.

Comment: If fact i am typing this comments in a new tap and left the other one in which I am trying to update my original post with. It says I can't post a picture, yet. Well hell with that and then I try to ignore the pic and input just the error message but the repos sources appear to be links, so you see how that goes for me.

Comment: @MarcoOz Mark the error message as code

Answer (score 3):

This one should do (make sure to replace `us` with your country prefix):

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main universe restricted multiverse
```